# How to help my 2-month-old, who hasn't pooped for 4 days, to poop?

Tags: newborn, elimination

My baby has completed two months and I feed him both breast milk and formula. He used to poop at least once every day or even after every feed before. But this suddenly stopped and he hasn't pooped for 4 days. He shows signs of discomfort after the feed, but otherwise he is fine. Still what shall I do to help him poop?

Comment: This is not necessarily a "visit the emergency room" issue, but it does warrant a call to your doctor if you are concerned. As others have said, this can be perfectly normal. Please only take medical advice from your baby's doctor, and follow your gut as a parent.

Comment: totally normal for babies. Ours went 12 days and suffered no lasting issues.

Answer (score 6):

It can be normal for breastfed babies not to poop for a few days at a time after the first few weeks of their lives. Formula fed babies usually should poop each day. This is because babies can digest breast milk very efficiently. I don't know what proportion breastmilk/formula you are giving but if it's more breastmilk than formula, this may be perfectly normal and you don't need to do anything.

http://www.nhs.uk/conditions/pregnancy-and-baby/pages/nappies.aspx

"Newborn babies who are breastfed may poo at each feed in the early weeks, then, after about six weeks, not have a poo for several days. Formula-fed babies may poo up to five times a day when newborn, but after a few months this can go down to once a day."

https://www.nct.org.uk/parenting/whats-your-babys-nappy

"After the first week: babies continue to wee and poo several times each day for the first few weeks. After that time, some (not all) babies poo much less often. Breastfed babies may go many days without producing any poo at all – that’s normal, too. As long as your baby is growing well, and the poo he produces is soft, you don’t need to be worried. Ask your health visitor about this, if you need to."

If you are still worried then definitely check with your doctor before administering any home remedies.

Answer (score 3):

This what worked for us some times:

Lay your child in their back, grab their feet, and move their legs in a 'bicycling' motion. Bring their legs up and in then stretch them out. Repeat.

We called it the "Poop Olympics."

Comment: And... Watch out!